# Rounding off and storing just that value for currency

Tags: .net, precision

What is the way to round off a variable and store it rounded off so that if it goes to DB, it goes off exactly as it was being displayed.

For example, in calculating a total for a order after taxes, etc.., while it is displaying just two digits to the user like 12.67, it was actually being stored in the database unrounded.

Right now, I am working around it by doing String.Format("{0:f2", total) and then converting it back to double and then use it to display/store in DB, but there's gotta be a better way.

I saw in an example code like this

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(
    System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.ModelBuilder modelBuilder) {
    modelBuilder.Entity<Movie>().Property(p => p.Price).HasPrecision(18, 2);
}
```

Is there a way to do that precision setting without using entity?

I am using custom built classes for business objects, maybe there is an annotation that I would be able to use?

Comment: You are asking for trouble when you store monetary values in `double`. Use `decimal` for that purpose.

Comment: Yeah, I second "don't use double for currency". Floats are stored in binary, and many common, simple numbers in decimal repeat in binary, resulting in a rounding problem. Ask your compiler if 0.1 + 0.1 + 0.1 == 0.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131275.aspx. There are several overloads so you can choose the best fit for your need.